# How to get cardano-node to work with public systemd sockets?

Tags: cardano-node

I get no errors but no traffic and am at a loss. A couple of things:

- I load a new service from file cardano-node.xml: `firewall-cmd --permanent --new-service-from-file=/usr/lib64/firewalld/services/cardano-node.xml`
- I reload so it becomes runtime: `firewall-cmd --reload`
- I see it in my default zone, allowing two ports, that match the TCP sockets handed by systemd. `netstat -ap | grep <port>` shows it, though as systemd. grep cardano shows something else:

```
    tcp6       0      0 [::]:29171              [::]:*                  LISTEN      1/systemd
    tcp        0      0 localhost:12788         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4513/cardano-node
```

- When inspecting with Wireshark, without passing sockets both an A and AAAA query is made, the former giving me an answer and my node starts downloading. When passing sockets only the AAAA query is made and the node does nothing.

I've set the scribe to JournalSK and debug level to info but there's nothing to go on. In fact, I remember more output using stderr/stdin with a simple `cardano-node run`, so I suspect something is off here too.

```
setupScribes:
  - scKind: JournalSK
    scName: journal
    scFormat: ScText
    scRotation: null

# For the Katip logging backend this specifies the default scribes that trace
# output is sent to if it is not configured to be sent to other scribes.
defaultScribes:
  - - JournalSK
    - journal
```

Is Katip and EKGViewBK something that needs to be installed separately or are they libraries used internally?

Comment: You're looking at firewall but socket activation is at systemd level. Can you share your unit files for the sockets and your node service?

Comment: Sure here you go: https://paste.ee/p/CJLcz 

It's my understanding once the service gets started the sockets get passed to it. I assumed no traffic was getting out and thought firewall.

Comment: I did a little digging and it looks like an A query is never made when using the premade sockets so the node never gets it's peers and nothing happens!

Comment: I guess the lack of an answer section means relays-new.cardano-node.iohk.io doesn't support IPv6? Also, are the IP's in the IPv4 response *relays* or my closest peers? Sorry, I am learning as I go. Look forward to knowing what I'm doing wrong!